# Simple way to add "the loop" from Wordpress into any html/php template (that is not made for wordpress)

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress

im looking **easy steps** for convert any html/php template into a very simple wordpress theme for personal use. I have a [site](http://www.elreporte.tk), in there i want news at the begining using the wordpress interface, i worked a lot with wordpress and i made some themes, but modifing already made ones, so i didnt care a lot about the code.

So, lookin in internet i dint found a good step by step tutorial in order to create a simple theme in wordpress from 0. Remember that i dont need sidebars, widgets and soo, i only need "the loop", or, the last 3 post made.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's as simple as installing wordpress correctly and then including the wp-blog-header file into your pages. Doing so will give you access to all of WP's functions.

```
require('/path/to/wp-blog-header.php');
$posts = get_posts('arguments');
```

Comment: please can you be more specific about the arguments ?